# Как форматировать жесткий диск с помощью C++?

Tags: c++

создаю программу для форматирования жесткого диска через свою программу. Но как не знаю, точнее знаю что можно через SHFormatDrive(); Но не уме обращаться с ним, как должен быть выглядеть код при этом?

```
cin >> (path1);
SHFormatDrive (0, toupper(path1[0])-'A', SHFMT_OPT_FULL, 1);
```

Comment: [Функция SHFormatDrive на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762169(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: можешь объяснить о UINT ?

Comment: А вам зачем? тру убер вирус написать хотите? :D

Comment: hwnd это идентификатор окна, здесь можно вписать ноль. drive - это номер диска, 0 - диск а, 1 - диск b и т.д. fmtID - всегда SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT. options - опции форматирования.

Например форматировать диск A с опциями по умолчанию: SHFormatDrive(0,0,SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT,0);

В MSDN хорошо написано, просто по-английски)

Comment: system("format c:");

Ну, м.б. еще какие-нибудь флаги, чтобы без вопросов.

Comment: Срочно идти спать; Срочно идти учить теорию;

Comment: @mikillskegg я очень хочу научиться хорошо программировать на С++, только вот не знаю с какого пособия или с чего начать правильно, вот и поэтому учусь по ходу создания программ, таким образом накапливаю знания. Может это и не правильный подход, может вы подскажете мне что-то или дадите совет?

Comment: А зачем сразу форматировать диск, если только учишься? Если хочешь работать с системой, то ИМХО лучше работать с программной частью, затем к харду лезть. Ну, скажем, работа с реестром, с файлами...

Comment: @navi1893, path1=='c', path1 - это строка (точнее даже указатель на начало строки), а 'c' - это символ. Их между собой сравнивать нельзя. Можно сравнивать path1[0]=='c', т.е. с первым символом строки.

Comment: просто вот создал программу, которая копирует, перемещает, удаляет, переименовывает файла, просто хочу добавить к нему и форматирование,вот и поэтому. А что ты посоветуешь начинающему? с чего мне начать, что программировать вначале, что прочесть ну вот дай советы новичку ) @ALEX_LAY_PRO @insolor

P.S @insolor спасибо, код сработал!

Comment: @navi1893, прочтите и **тщательно выполните упражнения** K&R (Б. Керниган, Д. Ритчи "Язык программирования Си"). 99% ошибок и вопросов через месяц-другой отпадут.

Comment: Сорри за оффтоп. Просто интересно.
Как отлаживать\тестить такую программу при написании?)

Comment: @navi, 99.9% того, что ты делаешь на "с++", с небольшими изменениями (типа замены cin/cout на scanf/printf) будет работать на си. Собственно С++ начнется тогда, когда ты дойдешь до ООП.

Comment: Можно форматировать дискетки, или выделить раздел диска для опытов, или тестировать на виртуальной машине, короче вариантов много

Comment: спасибо, прям щас начну читать!

Comment: я на флешке испробовал )

Answer (score 4):

В [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762169(v=vs.85).aspx) же все написано, английский учи)

То что после имени функции в скобках - это параметры.

Первый парметр - идентификатор "родительского" окна. Т.к. предполагается что программа консольная, то пишем 0.

Второй параметр - номер диска, если 0 - то диска А, если 1 - то диск B, 2 - диск C и т.д.

Третий параметр - всегда такой.

Четвертый параметр - если 0 то все по умолчанию, если 1 - то быстрое форматирование, если 2 - то создать загрузочную дискету (если выбранный диск - флопик)

Форматирование не начнется автоматически, пользователю еще нужно будет нажать кнопку "начать"

**UPD** То что написно в MSDN:

```
DWORD SHFormatDrive( __in  HWND hwnd, UINT drive, UINT fmtID, UINT options);
```

-- это прототип функции, он показывает какой тип значения функция возвращает (в данном случае это DWORD, просто 4-байтовое целое число без знака) и типы и имена ее параметров (это называется формальными параметрами). При вызове функции не нужно писать тип возвращаемого значения, а вместо формальных параметров нужно писать фактические параметры, то есть конкретные значения или переменные. Типы параметров (HWND, UINT и прочее __in) писать тоже не нужно.

Теперь, допустим у тебя в path1 лежит буква диска (будем считать что сама буква лежит в самом начала этой строки). Чтобы отформатировать этот диск нужно сделать вот что:

```
SHFormatDrive (0, toupper(path1[0])-'A', SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT, 0);
```

Что же это за второй параметр такой? А вот что это:

- path1[0] - берем первый символ в строке path1
- toupper(path1[0]) - переводим этот символ в верхний регистр, например если было 'g' то стало 'G'
- toupper(path1[0])-'A' - вычисляем разницу между полученным символом и символом 'A'. К примеру если пользователь ввел букву 'A', то разница будет равна 0, если 'B' - то 1 и так далее, то есть то что нам и нужно.

Кстати, чтобы функция SHFormatDrive заработала, нужно вначале вставить `#include <Shlobj.h>`, про это тоже написано в той же статье MSDN почти в самом низу в табличке в строке header. Чтобы заработал toupper нужно подключить `#include <locale>`

**UPD2** Чтобы SHFormatDrive работала в Dev-C++, нужно в начале исходника, где-нибудь после инклудов вствить две строки:

```
__declspec(dllimport) WINAPI DWORD SHFormatDrive(HWND hwnd, UINT drive, UINT fmtID, UINT options);
#define SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT 0xFFFF
```

или, так как у нас тут c++, то вторая строка должна выглядеть так:

```
const int SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT = 0xFFFF;
```

или просто вручную в вызове функции заменить `SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT` на 0xFFFF.

Comment: Спасибо за труд!

тогда так будет? но он ругается на SHFMT_OPT_FULL

SHFormatDrive (0, toupper(path1[0])-'A', SHFMT_OPT_FULL, 1);

Ошибка: `SHFMT_OPT_FULL' undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: `#include <Shlobj.h>` подключил?

Comment: да, но все же такая же ошибка, он не узнает ее.
Ошибки:
`SHFMT_OPT_FULL' undeclared (first use this function)
`SHFormatDrive' undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: dev c++, вот выложил код

Comment: Вставь вначале исходника #define SHFMT_OPT_FULL 0x0001

Comment: А кстати SHFMT_OPT_FULL должен быть вместо последней 1, а вместо SHFMT_OPT_FULL должно быть SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT.
P.S. Исправил в ответе